# How to save information with bash in the system?

Tags: bash

I am using command line with bash in Mac OS X. I will ask in my script:

```
Enter your password?
>
Do you want to save it and do not ask this more?
```

The password is to unzip a file. To do this, it always has to be entered, but I want it to only be entered once.

I can easily save it in a text file, but that is too obvious.

So I want to save it in the system. Windows has the "Windows Registry". Is there a similar system in Mac OS X (or Unix) that I can save it in and it will not be lost?

Or is there another way to save the password and it will be more secure? I know if someone runs the script with debug mode (showing how the command line is created) he will easy find the password, but he will have to get the computer, so is a kind of physical security.

Comment: Just an idea: Use some sort of key-ring that can be accessed in a shell script. The key-ring has to be unlocked first by the user sitting in front of the box, so it should be _quite_ secure.

Comment: It't a bit cumbersome, but [this blog post](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2011/11/using-keychain-for-secure-text-on-os-x.html) explains how to use the Mac OS X keychain from a script.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the way system passwords are stored: use a plain text file but store a checksum instead of plain text password. It would be best of the file wasn't accessible to the user, but even if it is, it's not that easy to reverse a checksum. Suppose you read the password into variable `password`. Then, you could do something like `echo "$password" | sha1sum - > password_file`. Then at next login, run the password provided by user through the same command and compare results. This way you can check if they entered the correct password without storing the password in cleartext.

Answer (score 0):

Either use your OS's keyring (OSX has something like this), or store it in plain text. Don't pretend that you are secure when you are not. If you cannot store things securely, then store them in plain sight, so the user is not given a false sense of security.